# GCC sometimes doesn't inline std::array::operator[]

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, optimization, inline

I have a complex program which uses `std::array<double, N>` for small values of N.  It uses `operator[]` to get values from these arrays.

I have discovered that GCC 6.1 with `-O2` or `-O3` does not inline these calls, leading to these C++ arrays being slower than their C equivalents.

Here's the generated assembly:

```
340 <std::array<double, 8ul>::operator[](unsigned long) const>:

340:  48 8d 04 f7             lea    (%rdi,%rsi,8),%rax
344:  c3                      retq   
345:  90                      nop
346:  66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
34d:  00 00 00
```

The very same code is emitted for each size of array (since there is no bounds checking).

A loop over such an array looks like this:

```
4c0:  e8 7b fe ff ff          callq  340 <std::array<double, 8ul>::operator[](unsigned long) const>
4c5:  be 07 00 00 00          mov    $0x7,%esi
4ca:  4c 89 f7                mov    %r14,%rdi
4cd:  48 89 44 24 78          mov    %rax,0x78(%rsp)

...6 more copies of this...

4d2:  e8 69 fe ff ff          callq  340 <std::array<double, 8ul>::operator[](unsigned long) const>
4d7:  48 89 44 24 70          mov    %rax,0x70(%rsp)
4dc:  31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
4de:  4c 89 ef                mov    %r13,%rdi
```

This seems obviously bad.  The problem is that small test programs don't elicit this behavior.

So my question is: how can I get GCC to tell me why it isn't inlining these one-instruction calls, and/or make it inline them?  Obviously I can't modify the `<array>` header file to add `__attribute__((inline))`.

Comment: File a bug against GCC?

Comment: @Brian: I'm not sure it's a bug...I expect some heuristic in GCC is making it think that this code is actually better for some reason.  The question here is how I can make GCC tell me what it's thinking, and/or change that.

Comment: But if you file a bug, then you can get the GCC developers to explain it to you. ;-)

Comment: There are various flags to dump things, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Developer-Options.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the optimizer of GCC 5 and 6 which manifests when using `__attribute__(("unroll-loops"))` in combination with `-ffast-math` or related options.

You can see it in action here: https://godbolt.org/g/ZBGCDB

This code reproduces the error if you compile with `-O3 -ffast-math`:

```
#include <array>

typedef std::array<double, 2> Array;

void foo(Array& a) __attribute__((optimize("unroll-loops")));

void foo(Array& a)
{
  for (size_t ii = 0; ii < a.size(); ++ii)
    a[ii] = 1.0;
}
```

It works as expected without `-ffast-math`, or if compiled with GCC 4.9, GCC 7 or later, or Clang.

Comment: Did you use any of the *dump* flags (as suggested by @T.C) to see what GCC is thinking and why it doesn't inline the calls?

Comment: @Nawaz: No.  I realized that the problem only occurs with the combination of {GCC 5/6, fast-math, unroll-loops} before I made any sense of those dump flags.